# Difference of setting the font-size on the div vs h1

Tags: html, css

What is the difference between setting some properties directly on the `div` container vs directly on the element in it. For example `font-size`:

```
<div class="the_last_of_us">
  <h5>Cookie Settings</h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Major different between setting the `font-size` on `div` vs `h1` or `h5` in the above example is, setting the `font-size` will not be inherited by the `h5` by default, as it will pick the styles from the **User Agent Stylesheet**, unless you explicitly define it to inherit, for example

```
h5 {
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

Whereas setting the `font-size` explicitly on the `h5` will override the user agent stylesheet and set the `font-size` you have defined for the `h5` element.

---

In other scenarios, it makes sense to set the properties on the Parent element, which will be inherited by a few elements. This will help you keep your selector specificity low. For example, setting `color` to the `div` can be inherited by the `h1` element.

So instead of a selector with a property like

```
div h5 {
  color: #f00;
}
```

You can use

```
div {
  color: #f00; /* Also applies color to any element inside 
                  the div which can inherit color from the parent element */
}
```

Comment: Based on your answer setting the `font-site` on the parent `div` will have no effect on the child `h1` and will not override the **User agent stylesheet** but this is not happening with me. When setting the `font-size` on the parent `div` the size of font on the child `h1` tag will be different than the default on coming from the **User agent stylesheet**.

**code**
`<div><h1>Some text</h1></div>`
`div { font-size: x-large; }`